# How to find a subspace with maximum dimension that doesn't include $k$ special vectors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, coding-theory

Assume $V_n = \{(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n), a_i \in \mathbb{GF}(2)\}$ and $k$ linearly independent vectors of $V_n$. How to find a subspace with maximum dimension that doesn't include these $k$ vectors?

Comment: Each $a_i$ is a matrix? Or $a_i\in\mathbb Z_2$?

Comment: @ShuchangZhang $a_i\in\mathbb Z_2$

Answer (score 2):

The dimension is always $\;n-1\;$ as we can always find a hyperplane not containing any of  the $\;k\;,\;k<n\;$ , lin. ind. vectors , say $\;\{v_1,...,v_k\}\;$.

**Proof:** First, complete the above set to a basis of $\;V_n\;$: $\;\{v_1,...,v_k,v_{k+1},...,v_n\}\;$ , and now define

$$\phi\in V_n^*\;,\;\;\phi(v_i)=\begin{cases}1&,\;\;i=1,2,...,k\\{}\\0&,\;\;i=k+1,...,n\end{cases}$$

Clearly $\;\phi\;$ is a non-zero linear functional and as such its kernel is a hyperplane (i.e., maximal subspace), and it contains none of $\;v_1,...,v_k\;$

Note that the definition field is irrelevant here.

Comment: Nice. Is there any reason to not just take the sum-of-all-coordinates linear form? (By the way, if $k=0$ the answer is of course the full space.)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, @MarcvanLeeuwen, but I've always been fond of lin. functionals and hyperplanes, and it works fine in the more interesting infinite dimensional case, where coordinates and their sum can be problematic

Comment: Well what I meant is that "$\phi(v_i)=1$ for all $i$" is shorter to write than your by-cases clause. And taking the sum of all coordinates on a basis works in infinite dimension as well: an expression on a basis is a linear combination, and as such there can only be finitely many nonzero coefficients. Also, you can always prescribe _arbitrary_ values on a basis to define a linear map.

Comment: Right on, @MarcvanLeeuwen. I guess I'm just too used to the dual basis and stuff.